# Trouble with appending to a JTextArea outside the GUI class

Tags: java, append, client, chat, jtextfield

I'm trying to enable changing the text of my JTextArea from outside the GUI-class. I think I know how I'm supposed to do it, it just doesn't work.

I declare and initialize the JTextArea like this:

```
JTextArea typeField = new JTextArea();
```

And then I have this method inside my GUI-class (but outside of the constructor, of course):

```
public void setText(String text){
    typeField.append(text);
}
```

I read in another thread here that this is how you're supposed to do. But the compiler doesn't approve of this, and says "typeField cannot be resolved" on the line where I use the append method. I think what I'm trying to accomplish is quite simple and I really don't get why this doesn't work. Maybe I've done some silly mistake? If so, I can't find it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm going to post my code here anyway, hoping someone will be able to help me!
So what I'm trying to do is implement the client part of a chat program. I have two parts. The chat client part and the GUI part.

The chat part:

```
package chat;

import java.io.\*;
import java.net.\*;
import javax.swing.\*;
import java.awt.\*;
import java.awt.event.\*;

public class ChatClient{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

    //ChatWindow chatWindow = new ChatWindow();

    //Default values.
    String host = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 2000;

    //If the user starts the program with "java ChatClient <host>"
    if (args.length == 1) {
        host = args[0]; //Catches the first parameter.                
    }

    //If the user starts the program with "java ChatClient <host> <port>"
    else if (args.length == 2) {
        host = args[0]; //Catches the first parameter.
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //Catches the second parameter.
    }

    //If the user sends too many parameters.
    else if (args.length > 2) {
        System.out.println("You have sent too many parameters.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    //Sets the host and port as the titel of the window.
    //chatWindow.setWindowTitle(host + " " + port);

    try (   
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);

        PrintWriter out = 
            new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = 
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in))
    ) {
        String userInput;
        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(userInput);
            System.out.println("Server: " + in.readLine());
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't not find host " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + host);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

And the GUI part (these two classes are defined in the same file, so I don't need to repeat the imported librarys):

```
class ChatWindow extends JFrame {
public ChatWindow () {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //A JPanel containing the "message board";
    JPanel messageBoard = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    //A JTextArea showing all the messages.
    JTextArea messageField =  new JTextArea();
    messageField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470, 300));
    messageField.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    messageBoard.add(messageField);
    add(messageBoard, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //A JPanel containing the TextField where the user writes his messages as well as the button to send these messages
    JPanel typeBoard = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    //A JTextArea where the user writes his messages.
    JTextArea typeField = new JTextArea();
    typeField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 100));
    typeField.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    typeBoard.add(typeField);

    //A button used to send a message.
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    typeBoard.add(sendButton);

    add(typeBoard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setSize(500, 470);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
}

public void setText (String text) {
    messageField.append("\n" + text);
}

public void setWindowTitle (String title) {
    setTitle(title);
}
}

class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        //Not implemented yet
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the answer to this question turned out to be really simple. And it goes something like this:

Since I'm declaring and initializing the variable `messageField` inside the constructor, it does not exist outside of the constructor. So when I try to use the value of that variable outside of the constructor - inside my `setText(String text)`-method, it obviously didn't work work.

What I needed to do was to declare that variable outside of the constructor, like this:

```
class ChatWindow extends JFrame {
JTextArea messageField; //This line does the trick!

public ChatWindow () {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //A JPanel containing the "message board";
    JPanel messageBoard = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    //A JTextArea showing all the messages.
    messageField =  new JTextArea();
    messageField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(470, 300));
    messageField.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    messageBoard.add(messageField);
    add(messageBoard, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    //A JPanel containing the TextField where the user writes his messages as well as the button to send these messages
    JPanel typeBoard = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    //A JTextArea where the user writes his messages.
    JTextArea typeField = new JTextArea();
    typeField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 100));
    typeField.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    typeBoard.add(typeField);

    //A button used to send a message.
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    typeBoard.add(sendButton);

    add(typeBoard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setSize(500, 470);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try this :

```
public synchronized void setText(String text){
    typeField.append(text);
}
```

`synchronized` will synchro the two threads.
You can read more here : [Docs Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. And also, since I'm pretty sure having two classes doesn't count as having two different threads, I don't think synchronizing is the issue. But thanks anyway!